# Importing csv file to sql- my txt have ' ' and , between each field

Tags: sql-server, import, export-to-csv

I need to import 2 `.txt` files into my SQL Server table. Below are the two parts of my code - first is creating the table, and second part is populating it with the first file.

The fist part is fine, but the second part gives me an error-

> *Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (TestAcctID).
>
>   Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (TestAcctID).*

```
Create Table TestAcct(TestAcctID int identity(1,1),
                 LastName varchar(30), 
                 FirstName varchar(30), 
                 PhoneNumber varchar(10),
                 AccountType varchar(5),
                 AccountNumber varchar(30),
    constraint PKTestAcct Primary Key(TestAcctID))

/*Insert info from .txt file*/

BULK INSERT TestAcct
FROM 'c:\Users\lraffi\desktop\File1.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

I think my problem is that the text in my CSV file have `''` around each word - I wrote already for the `FIELD TERMINATOR= ','` and `ROW TERMINATOR= '\n'` -  but how do I write that there is also `' '`? Does anyone think that that is the problem??

Here is the content of my .txt files:

File1.txt: 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'AccountNumber', 'PhoneNumber', 'AccountType' 'Bob','Jones','123456789','8451111111','RES' 'Jane','DOE','987654321','8452222222', 'COM' 'Mike', 'Smith', '123459876','8453333333','RES'

File2.txt: 'RecordCount=3' 'AccountNumber', 'PhoneNumber', 'AccountType','FirstName', 'LastName' '222222222','8454444444','RES','Bill','James' '333333333','8455555555', 'COM','John','Barton' '444444444','8456666666','RES','William', 'Stark' 'End'

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data in the text file you are importing?

Comment: If the problem is that there are '' around each word and you don't want these at all, do a simple replace in the files replacing ' with nothing (since we're talking about two files, that would be fast).  **Related to your error:** Your column in the table doesn't match what's in the files.  TestAcctID is an INT and is an identity, yet the error indicates that this isn't the case in the files.  Could you post the first two rows from the files?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a format file. Here's a couple examples to get you started

- [Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx)
- [Help with Bulk insert with text qualifier "](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/c484899e-6d77-4441-9737-696d6299bb85)
- [Sample XML Format Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191234%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

You will then need to account for the text qualifiers (') in the format file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="'," MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="','" MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="'\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="30"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="FirstName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="LastName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="AccountNumber" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```